# How to queue commands

Tags: scripts, scheduled

Suppose I have jobs to run one after another, how can I queue them up and if possible still retain the output/log each script produces. (eg. I can use at to schedule tasks but I dont get the log/output of each app)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to run several commands interactively, just separate them with a semicolon:

```
foo ; bar ; baz
```

If you want to queue a batch of commands to be executed in the background when the system isn't too busy and possibly after you have logged out, you can use the `batch` command.  The output of jobs run with `batch`, `at`, or `cron` is emailed to you.  For that to work, you need to setup a local mail server.

Comment: +1, unless you have a specific reason to use `&&`, this is better.

Answer (score 3):

Write the commands with **&&** between them eg : `command1 && command2`

Note : the second command won't be executed if the first command returns an error

Comment: You can separately save the stdout of each with normal bash redirection: `command1 > afile && command2 > anotherfile`

Answer (score 1):

If this is a long list of commands, or you're going to do this often enough, I would make a script to do it for you.

shell scripts of this nature are extremely easy.

```
#!/bin/bash
foo
bar
baz
```

Simply put this text into a file, turn execution on (`chmod +x myscript`) and then `./myscript` and off you go.

This will execute commands `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` in order assuming that all of them block.

If you ever want to do something more complicated see the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)